# CakePHP 2.3 & jQuery 1.8: Sending arbitrary data via ajax to Cakephp controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

For complicated reasons not worth getting into, I need to send an array of data to a Cakephp controller, via AJAX, and preferably (though not necessarily) by jQuery.

I know how to do this just fine when serializing a form, which is why I'm a little surprised that I'm having the trouble I am. Here's my code:

```
var inputs  = Array(val1, val2, val3);  
    var json_inputs = JSON.stringify(inputs);

    $.ajax({
    url:"http://www.domain.tld/controller/action/",
    data:json_inputs,
    }).done(function() {
        alert('made it back');
    });
```

I know my request is getting to the controller because I put this in it:

```
public function controllerAction() {
    fopen('test.txt', 'w+');
    fwrite(print_r($this->request()), true);
}
```

But `test.txt` is empty no matter how I tweak this. Anyone?

Comment: If you're trying to debug Ajax requests I recommend using Chrome developer tools. You can see HTTP requests in the network tab, and the request and response content (header/body) if you click on them.

Comment: I always forget about this aspect of Chrome'd dev. tools. You're right of course. Ty for the reminder/tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misplaced a bracket for [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and are missing the file handle for [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php):

```php
$handle = fopen('test.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($handle, print_r($this->request(), true));
```

Comment: Well spotted, I was mis-reading the question, thought OP meant the *request* was empty

Comment: Haven't yet had chance to go see if my JavaScript was working all along, but I can tell you that yesterday was just one of those days where the code won't go and you just want to run off into the mountains in a loin cloth. This is also how I missed these really obvious errors; I'm surprised my IDE even let me do this. : / Ty guys.